# Output all mp4 files from multiple directories

Tags: php, directory, filenames, opendir

I have a problem. I want to output all file names that have an extension .mp4. The following code could make it, but it only outputs from one directory.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('/media/AB12-34/DCIM/100DCIM')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && strtolower(substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1)) == 'mp4')
        { 
$thelist .= '<p><td><option value="'.$file.'">'.$file. '</option></td>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
```

I want the script to output all .mp4 files from all directories that are in `/media/AB*/DCIM/100DCIM` (please note the star) directory. Is there any way of doing this using `opendir` command? Tried with * but it was not working.

Comment: Use `glob()` Here you can use `*`. `$files = glob('/media/AB*/DCIM/100DCIM/*'); print_r($files);`

Comment: @AdrianPreuss: glob doesn't recurse.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP5's in-built [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * RecursiveDirectoryIterator function to get media.
 *
 * @param string $base_dir
 * @param array $extentions
 * @return array
 */
function get_media($base_dir, $extentions = array('mp4')) {
    if(!file_exists($base_dir)) return array();

    $extensions = implode('|', $extentions);
    $directory  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($base_dir);
    $iterator   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
    $regex      = new RegexIterator($iterator, "/^.+\.$extensions$/i", RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

    $ret        = array();
    foreach ($regex as $filename=>$object) {
        $ret[] = $filename;
    }
    return $ret;
}

//print_r( get_media('/media/', array('mp4')) );

$thelist = '<select size="1" name="?">';
foreach (get_media('/media/', array('mp4')) as $file)
{
    $thelist .= '<option value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</option>';
}
$thelist .= '</select>';

echo $thelist;
?>
```

Edit (added time, see comment):

As you basically have the full path to the file, you could add `filectime($filename);` within the iterator function or add it outside when doing the display loop, below is doing it inside the function.

```
<?php
/**
 * RecursiveDirectoryIterator function to get media.
 *
 * @param string $base_dir
 * @param array $extentions
 * @return array
 */
function get_media($base_dir, $extentions = array('mp4')) {
    if(!file_exists($base_dir)) return array();

    $extensions = implode('|', $extentions);
    $directory  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($base_dir);
    $iterator   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
    $regex      = new RegexIterator($iterator, "/^.+\.$extensions$/i", RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

    $ret        = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($regex as $filename=>$object) {
        $ret[$i]['filename'] = $filename;
        $ret[$i]['filetime'] = filectime($filename);
        $i++;
    }
    return $ret;
}

//print_r( get_media('/media/', array('mp4')) );

$thelist = '<select size="1" name="?">';
foreach (get_media('/media/', array('mp4')) as $file)
{
    $thelist .= '<option value="'.$file['filename'].'">'.$file['filename'].' - '.date("F j, Y, g:i a",$file['filetime']).'</option>';
}
$thelist .= '</select>';

echo $thelist;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. @Loz Cherone. That worked fine. Maybe you have another idea, how to print out the modified dates, instead of filenames? Thank you again!!

Comment: nice! Thank you very much. I was looking for a solution for almost 2 weeks, you got it in 1 hour!

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom np, glad to help.

Comment: Hey @LozCheroneツ. I wanted to ask you something more if possible.
Now, if I take the path to filename, it appears something like this:
/media/AB12-34/DCIM/100DCIM\media1.mp4 (with the \ before filename)
But I want the path looking like this:
/media/AB12-34/DCIM/100DCIM/media1.mp4 (with the / before filename).
I know it does not make much difference, but if I want to use the path as a source URL in <video> tag, browser does not understand this backslash "\" and it cannot locate the file. Any way of changing the "\" into "/" ? Thank you!